# Getting a bar to scroll across the screen in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Basic question, I'm new to jQuery and this wont work.

Basically I'm trying to make a div (top_bar) start with width 0% and widen to be width 76%. When I open the page, the bar just isn't there (due to the initial width being 0%)

Here's the basic idea of what I had. I just don't know what to put as the arguments for animate().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top_bar').animate({$('#top_bar').width:"76%"}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. `animate()`'s first parameter takes an object with the styles that you want to set, not a selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top_bar').animate({width:"76%"}, 1000);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhmQ4/)

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is slightly off you do not need to select top_bar twice try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#top_bar').animate({width:"76%"}, 1000);
});
```

Check http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for more info, you first choose your selector then parse it and array off options. There are loads off example further down on the page.

See here for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/p6sGb/